# Spring STS does not work with Gradle

Tags: spring, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have downloaded Spring STS. I created a project (new spring starter project) and selected gradle buildship. It said I didn't have it and needed it from the marketplace.

I went to the marketplace, got it, restarted, created a sample gradle java project and compiled it to test.

I then selected to create a new spring starter project again and selected gradle.

It still says 'can not import using Gradle (Buildship) because Buildshiop Gradle Tooling is not installed....

Any ideas. Not having terribly good luck with this product, pivotal tc fails to start too.

I think I might just go back to Tomcat and Eclipse, which does work unless someone can point me in the right direction :)

thanks.

Comment: java version you are using?

Comment: if so please accept/vote it @Neil Walker

Answer (score 3):

After some investigation into this problem... STS has a version constraint on its BuildShip dependency. It doesn't work with BuildShip 2.0 and later.

The error message is not very helpful. Because STS can't link with Buildship version 2.0 and later. This makes it look to STS code as if Buildship is not installed. That's why the error message is awkward.

We'll be trying to fix this ASAP In the mean time, please install an older version of BuildShip.

I've just created an [issue ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues/90), so you can keep an eye on that ticket to remain informed about progress fixing it.

Update: a fix is now available from snapshot update site. See the issue ticket for further details. This fix will also be available in the next release of STS (i.e. STS version 3.8.4).

Comment: Thanks. I've actually just had to remove java 8 from my machine to get another bit of software running so STS does not work now, but I'll try it again when I go back. Thanks for raising the ticket and fixing it.