# Spring Tool Suite (STS) - Can not import using Gradle (Buildship)

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, gradle

Please, let me start by saying that I am aware of the following question: [Spring STS does not work with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41639980/spring-sts-does-not-work-with-gradle). However, the answer does not resolve my issue.

Here is information about my configuration and the issue.

**Java**:  java version "1.8.0_111"

**OS**: Win 10 Home

**Eclipse**: 
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Neon Release (4.6.0)
Build id: 20160613-1800

Software installed in Eclipse:

[image]

I also installed the legacy extension as advised in the question mentioned above.
[image]

Issue:

I try to create a new Gradle (buildship) via the Spring Getting Started Content but I keep getting the error: "**Can not import using Gradle (Buildship) because Buildship Gradle Tooling is not installed. You can install it from Eclipse Marketplace**".

[image]

I am unable to resolve this issue. Any suggestions how to resolve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has been resolved. See the issue update at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues/90

To install STS update from snapshot site, got to Help > Install New Software and add the update site https://dist.springframework.org/snapshot/IDE/nightly as mentioned in the issue ticket.

Worked for me.

Comment: thanks very much. I can confirm that the suggested solution worked for me as well!