# Can not import using Gradle (Buildship 1.x) because Buildship Gradle Tooling version 1.x is not installed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I am using Eclipse Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a). Eclipse is not allowing to create spring starter project with Type: Gradle (Buildship 1.x).

[image]

I have already installed Buildship Gradle Integration 2.0 installed in my eclipse.

[image]

I have already referred the below stackoverflow links. But couldn't find solution.

[Spring Tool Suite (STS) - Can not import using Gradle (Buildship)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41641459/spring-tool-suite-sts-can-not-import-using-gradle-buildship)

[Spring Tool Suite not possible to create new project with Gradle: Can not import using Gradle (STS) because STS Gradle Tooling is not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45376675/spring-tool-suite-not-possible-to-create-new-project-with-gradle-can-not-import)

please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says buildship 1.x, and the thing you installed says 2.  That could be the reason, but I normally use maven for spring projects.

Comment: I tried searching buldship 1.0 as well, but that is not getting listed at all in the eclipse market place.

Comment: You can just download a project from [link](http://start.spring.io) .  There's really no reason to even use that plugin unless you don't have access to the internet. It looks like your internet works fine.

Comment: https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/blob/master/docs/user/Installation.md

Comment: accepting your answer as it solved my purpose other way around but han't got a proper reason for my question. anyways thanks.